# Running docker run command on windows

Tags: windows, docker, localhost, containers

I am a beginner in docker and I am trying to run a Q&A website locally in my browser. I have found an open source container on the link https://hub.docker.com/r/zout84/askbot-docker. Here are the steps that I have done:

- I have downloaded docker toolbox DockerToolbox-19.03.1.exe to be able to run docker using my Windows terminal.
- Following the instructions on the above link I have run the command `docker run -v /tmp/askbot:/data/ -p 8080:80 -d zout84/askbot-docker`. Since I am on Windows I have replaced `/tmp/askbot:/data/` by a folder I have created.
- I have downloaded the container and put it a local folder that I called Docker_source. I have replaced `zout84/askbot-docker` by `C:\Docker_source` in the above `docker run` command

Now the error that I have is `docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.`

Please, any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error said, The repository has to be lower case. It is called `C:\Docker_source`. You got a capital "D" over there. change it to a "d"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have replaced all the capital letters by small letters, even C:\. Now the error is `docker: invalid reference format.`
Basically, the command now is 
`docker run -v c:\docker_dest -p 8080:80 -d c:\docker_source`. Where `c:\docker_source` contains the container files